# sample size calculation based on 95% CI half-width

Tags: sample-size

Assume the null hypothesis of a response rate is 10%. We need to calculate the sample size needed based on estimation of the response rate using maximum half-width of the two-sided 95% confidence interval of <13.2% when response rate is expected to be 20%-50%. The answer is n=60 subjects, but how this sample size is calculated? Thanks.

Comment: You pose two different questions: the one about the confidence interval width has nothing to do with the null hypothesis you state.  Indeed, if you will assume a response between 20% and 50% then your assumptions along imply the null hypothesis of 10% is false.